# How to remove item from list in Android

Tags: android, arrays

In my application I have **2 list** and maybe some items same between lists. 
I want to check these lists and **remove same items**. 
I write below codes but after run application show me error and crashed application! 
**My codes:**

```
if (ALLERGIC_LIST.isNotEmpty()) {
    ALLERGIC_LIST.forEach { allergic ->
        //Added to user list
        userLocalList.add(LocalDataModel(allergic.faName.toString(), true, 0, allergic.id!!))
        userRecyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        //Remove from temp list
        dataListTemp.forEach { temp ->
            Log.e("AllergicLogs","${allergic.id} - ${temp.id}")
            if (allergic.id == temp.id) {
                dataListTemp.remove(temp)
            }
        }
    searchList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Error message in Logcat:**

```
2022-10-13 08:44:07.617 11990-11990/com.myapp E/AllergicLogs: 1791538835 - 1749914577
2022-10-13 08:44:07.617 11990-11990/com.myapp E/AllergicLogs: 1791538835 - 1762590770
2022-10-13 08:44:07.617 11990-11990/com.myapp E/AllergicLogs: 1791538835 - 1791538835
2022-10-13 08:44:07.617 11990-11990/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 11990
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
        at com.myapp.AllergicFragment.onViewCreated$lambda-14$lambda-7(AllergicFragment.kt:233)
        at com.myapp.AllergicFragment.$r8$lambda$VH4SurM8Hl44Zx-Iy-J2iPtdh8g(AllergicFragment.kt)
        at com.myapp.AllergicFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onChanged(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

How can I fix it and remove same item?

Comment: You can't remove an item from a Collection while iterating over that Collection-  that screws up the iterator and causes a ConcurrentModificationException.  Really the easiest way to do this is rather than delete the item from the list, create a new list holding only the items that you didn't want to remove.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks my friend. can you help me for this and send to me true code for fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataListTemp.forEach { temp ->
            Log.e("AllergicLogs","${allergic.id} - ${temp.id}")
            if (allergic.id == temp.id) {
                dataListTemp.remove(temp)// Here is the error. You're doing concurrent modification here
                dataListTempDuplicate.remove(temp)//Instead delete from duplicate array
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend. yes, I know error for remove. but I don't know how can I fix it?!

Comment: create another array and copy its element onto that array and then delete from that array

Answer (score 1):

```
dataListTemp = dataListTemp.filter { dataItem->
    ALLERGIC_LIST.find {it.id == dataItem.id} == null
}
```

Filter removes all items that don't return true from the lambda.  The find function will check to see if there's an item with that id in the allergic list, or return null if not.  So if find returns a match, we return false in the filter lambda and skip that item.  If we don't, we return true from the lambda and keep it in the filtered list.

This replaces the entire outer foreach loop. Runtime will be O(n^2), but do was the original.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. I used your code. In this way does not show me any error, but again show same items!

Comment: Does dataListTemp hold the same items, or do the same items get displayed?  If the second, are you sure that you're grabbing the proper array when you display items-  anything named temp as a state variable scares me, because I have to wonder if you're ever updating the real values with the temp ones.